# HEAD Request using Playwright

Tags: web-scraping, playwright

1. Is it worth to make a head request in playwright ? which library

We are developing a web scrapping project using Playwright. There is a bunch of URLS which we need to crawl , some of the URLS could contain PDF/GDOCS content.
In order to identify the type of page content, before getting pageSource () - Is it a good idea to make a HEAD request and identify the MIME Type ?

1. if so, which class is the preferred one to make HEAD request ? Request or APIRequestContext ?
2. Is it too costly to open a context and close just for getting HEADERS
3. Also, Is it really necessary to make a HEAD request ? Wont some web domains block the traffic if there is multiple request attempts within a span of milliseconds ?